# Backup with root and restore without root

Tags: backup, restore

I have failed to backup and restore an app from my old to my new phone using [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28315/246747). The reason seem to be due to the app I want to backup is a "disallowed" type (`ALLOW_BACKUP:NO`) (I notice it later using Helium). First, it is strange that the answer linked did not mention that it only worsk for those app that are allowed to backup in their *Manifest*. Second, it seems that the only option is to do the backup with root, for instance by using Titanium. I don't mind to root my old phone to do the backup, but I would not like to root the new phone in which I want to restore the mentioned app. So is it posible to do the backup with root and then the restore without root, using for example titanium and Helium, respectively?

Comment: Before getting to the *How to* part, how will you root your old phone? If it involves unlocking bootloader, then your data is wiped on practically all devices.

Comment: I dont know, what kind of root do you suggest if I  am only interested  to backup an app?

Comment: You would need to read up on XDA or on this site how to root your particular device - if it involves unlocking bootloader, you are out of luck

Comment: @beeshyams unless it's the rare case where there exists a method to unlock the bootloader without a wipe. But as said, those cases are rare.

Comment: @Izzy: That's what I meant by *practically*

Comment: @beeshyams Ooops, yes, your first comment :blush:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, restoring the app-data from a backup of an app that has `allowBackup=false` will not work:

Helium uses AFAIR adb and if the app declares `allowBackup=false` you can neither create nor restore data of that app via `adb backup`.

Titanium does only work if the phone is rooted independently if you want to create or restore a backup.

The only chance to create a backup of an app with `allowBackup=false` is if the app provides an own backup/restore function within the app.

Comment: Thanks for answering, why do you think this thing about `allowBackup=false` was not pointed out in the post I [linked](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28315/246747), because it seems an elementary advice before users pretend to backup/restore without root, isn't it?

Comment: Because the answer was created at a time when the allowBackup "feature" was nearly never used. Only recently app developers use this feature more often. May be this happens because of the automatic Google app-data to cloud backup is active in newer Android version unless you disallow backup.